# How to initial a variable or array in sql server 2012

Tags: arrays, t-sql, variables, loops

I want to initialize a variable into the WHILE loop so that I can use that variable for further steps.
How can I initialize a varchar array for the SELECT Statement? I am Using it like this:

```
DECLARE @SerialNumber AS VARCHAR

WHILE (
        @SerialNumber = SELECT UnitInContainer.UnitSerialNumber
        FROM UnitInContainer
        WHERE ContainerCode = @Code
        ) IS NOT NULL
    SELECT TOP 1 @CreatedUserName = UnitInStep.CreatedByUserName,
        @CreatedOn = UnitInStep.CreatedOn,
        @DeactivatedOn = UnitInStep.DeactivatedOn,
        @UnitInContainerID = UnitInStep.UnitInContainerID,
        @UnitSerialNumber = UnitInStep.UnitSerialNumber,
        @ContainerCode = UnitInStep.ContainerCode,
        @StepSequence = UnitInStep.StepSequence,
        @RouterItemName = UnitInStep.RouterItemName,
        @RouterRevisionNumber = UnitInStep.RouterRevisionNumber
    FROM UnitInStep
    INNER JOIN RouterStepAttribute
        ON UnitInStep.RouterItemName = RouterStepAttribute.RouterItemName
            AND UnitInStep.RouterRevisionNumber = RouterStepAttribute.RouterRevisionNumber
            AND UnitInStep.StepSequence = RouterStepAttribute.StepSequenc
    WHERE GETDATE() BETWEEN UnitInStep.CreatedOn
            AND UnitInStep.DeactivatedOn RouterStepAttribute.StepTypeStepTypeValue = 'TestChamberAutoResult'
        AND UnitInStep.UnitSerialNumber = @SerialNumber
    END
```

Comment: Please format your code so we can read it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
DECLARE @SerialNumber AS VARCHAR

SELECT @SerialNumber = UnitInContainer.UnitSerialNumber
    FROM UnitInContainer
    WHERE ContainerCode = @Code

WHILE (@SerialNumber is not null)
BEGIN
    -- The longer select using @SerialNumber in the where clause

    SELECT @SerialNumber = UnitInContainer.UnitSerialNumber
        FROM UnitInContainer
        WHERE ContainerCode = @Code
END
```

It repeats the shorter select but you could put it in a function if that's a problem.